# Highlight Duplicate list item in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, duplicates, highlight, conditional-formatting

I have a SharePoint 2013 (The Cloud version) custom list where 1 column is a text field where contact numbers are keyed in. 
How can I get SharePoint to highlight duplicate values in that column so that every time a new item is added to the list, I'll know if the contact number has been used previously?

Ideally, here's what I'd get if I were to enter 816's details for the 2nd time:

**CNO....Name.......Issue** 
 816.....Blink........Login Problem (highlighted in red)
 907.....Sink.........Access Denied
 204.....Mink.........Flickering Screen
 816.....Blink........Blank Screen (highlighted in red)

I've been struggling with this for awhile and would be very grateful for any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SharePoint 2013 uses Client Side Rendering (CSR) as a *default rendering mode* I would recommend the following approach. Basically the idea is to customize List View on the client side as demonstrated below.

Assume the `Requests` list that contains `RequestNo` column.

The following JavaScript template is intended for highlighting the rows when list item with  `RequestNo` column occurs more then once:

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;

    var counts = getItemCount(rows,'RequestNo');  //get items count    

    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
      var count = counts[rows[i]["RequestNo"]];
      if (count > 1) 
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#ada";
      }
    }
  }
});


function getItemCount(items,propertyName)
{
   var result = {};
   for(var i = 0; i< items.length; i++) {
      var groupKey = items[i][propertyName];
      result[groupKey] = result[groupKey] ? result[groupKey] + 1 : 1;
   }
   return result;
}
```

**How to apply the changes**

Option 1:

Below is demonstrated probably one of easiest way how to apply those changes:

1. Open the page in `Edit` mode
2. Add `Content Editor` or `Script Editor` web part on the page
3. Insert the specified JavaScript template by enclosing it using
   `script` tag into web part

Option 2:

1. Save the specified JavaScript template as a file (let's name it duplicatehighlight.js) and upload it into Site Assets library
2. Open the page in `Edit` mode and find `JSLink` property in List View web part
3. Specify the value: `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/duplicatehighlight.js` and save the changes.

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Hi Vadim. I tried this, but now all my rows have been highlighted, not just the duplicate ones. I replaced 'RequestNo' in your script with the name of my column. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Hi, i verified the script again and it works for me exactly as demonstrated on image provided. if it displays all rows highlighted, probably all lines are duplicated (CNO column is duplicated in your case)?

Comment: Hi Vadim, Just an update: It finally worked when I chose a column other than my Title column. Thanks loads! However, is there any way to show the highlights without having to click on Edit Page first?

Comment: Hi, please try to apply the changes using option 2 (see the updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has some basic conditional formatting for Data View Web Parts and XSLT List Views, but the conditions you can use are rather limited. You can compare a field in the current item with a value that you specify. There are no formulas to count the number of items with the same name or similar, which would be the approach to use to identify duplicates.

If you need to identify duplicates, you may want to create a view that groups by the CNO number. Grouping will also include an item count, so you can run down the list and spot groups with more than one item.